# R: Using value of a named character variable as the name in a vector

Tags: r

To minimize repetition, I want to name a character variable, so I can reuse it. One use is a color scale, which I'm trying to do as vector of named characters.

Here's what I tried:

```
apple_name = "apple"
fruit_colors = c(apple_name = "red", "banana" = "yellow")
```

I am missing something basic here, because the resulting vector has the variable name `apple_name`, instead of its value `apple`.

```
> fruit_colors
apple_name     banana 
     "red"   "yellow"
```

Other things I unsuccessfully tried are `eval`,`get`, and `parse`

```
fruit_colors = c(eval(apple_name) = "red", "banana" = "yellow") [Error: unexpected '=' in "fruit_colors = c(eval(apple_name) ="]
fruit_colors = c(get(apple_name) = "red", "banana" = "yellow") [Error: unexpected '=' in "fruit_colors = c(get(apple_name) ="]
fruit_colors = c(parse(apple_name) = "red", "banana" = "yellow") [Error: unexpected '=' in "fruit_colors = c(get(apple_name) ="]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `setNames` as the `=` doesn't allow evaluation of objects to be passed on the `lhs` of `=` instead it does name it literally

```
setNames(c("red", "yellow"), c(apple_name, "banana"))
#apple   banana 
#"red" "yellow"
```

---

If we want to create a named vector, an option is to use `:=` in a `lst` (from `dplyr`) and `unlist` to create the `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
unlist(lst(!!apple_name := "red", "banana" = "yellow"))
#   apple   banana 
#   "red" "yellow"
```

Comment: A similar approach is to create the vector then add the names with `names(fruit_colors) <- c(apple_name, "banana")`

Comment: @BrianFisher yes, `setNames` does the assignment internally or with `names<-`